# fastest way converting multidimensional std::vector into one array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, stl, stdvector

I want to copy as little as possible. At the moment I'm using `num_t* array = new num_t[..]` and then copying each value of the multidimensional vector into `array` in a for-loop.

I'd like to find a better way to do this.

Comment: If it's that critical to you, then perhaps you should consider not using a `vector` to begin with.

Comment: @aces Is num_t  arithmetic type?

Comment: In any case, you should probably use a library's copy instead of your own loop. In c++ this is `<algorithm>`s `copy`.

Comment: BTW, you can use `vector` functions `data()` and `size()` in order to copy the entire data in a single function-call.

Comment: @barak: right! I could use data() - and I'm looking into solely using arrays and not std::vector.

Comment: You could write adapter - template class, that will behave like `num_t* array`, but will redirect read/write to vector. This will be fast to convert, but  access times will be slow.

Comment: So again - why do you have a `vector` in your code to begin with?

Comment: @barak: The code should be as generic as possible. So I use vector<vector<Point<num_t>>> with Point being a structure, which can be easily changed. Do you see an easy way around this?

Comment: You haven't explained why you want to use a native array when you have your data stored (generically) in a `vector`. So I'm not sure around what you're looking an easy way for.

Comment: @barak: Aha! I misunderstood your question. I need to copy the data from the vector to a GPU - which takes only array format.

Comment: are your inner vectors of the same size?

Comment: @m.s.: yes the inner vectors have the same size!

Comment: then I would **not** use vector<vector<T>> but instead store the 2 dimensional data e.g. in [row-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) in a flat vector<T>. Copying this vector is then very easy.

Comment: @m.s.: I think this might be the solution. If I have the data in a one-dimensional vector to begin with - i can access the array by reference without ever having to copy data around.

Comment: So what I've done is : `int* array1 = &myvect[1][0];
    int* array2 = &myvect[2][0];
    int* array3 = &myvect[3][0];` But how can I do this with only one 2D array instead of three 1D arrays?

Comment: I've tried using for-loops like this: `int *my_array[3];
    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
        my_array[i] = &my_vect[i][0];
    }` but the dimensions weren't correct.

Answer (score 2):

For arithmetic types you can use function `memcpy`. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v =
    {
        { 1 },
        { 1, 2 },
        { 1, 2, 3 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
    };

    for ( const auto &row : v )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    size_t n = 0;
    for ( const auto &row : v ) n += row.size();

    int *a = new int[n];
    int *p = a;

    for ( const auto &row : v )
    {
        std::memcpy( p, row.data(), row.size() * sizeof( int ) );
        p += row.size();
    }        

    for ( p = a; p != a + n; ++p ) std::cout << *p << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    delete []a;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 
1 2 
1 2 3 
1 2 3 4 

1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: thanks. I believe std::copy is faster than memcpy? no?

Comment: @aces I think that it is not faster. At least compilers use memcpy when initialize arrays of arithmetic types.

Comment: @aces In some platforms as for example IBM mainframe function memcpy is substituted for one machine command like MVCL

Comment: Why are you explicitly mentioning this for arithmetic types? Is `memcpy` no good to copy classes and structs?

Comment: @Maarten Bamelis  memcpy simply copies a set of unsigned characters. It knows nothing about the underlaying type and of course neither constructor is called.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Good point. Still, can it then be safely used on objects to **move** them around from one memory buffer to the other, e.g. in a container that needs to reallocate a bigger buffer and quickly copy it's data around?

Comment: @Maarten Bamelis  If a  container contains POD types then it is safe.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated in the comments your inner vectors of your `vector<vector<T>>` structure are of the same size. So what you are actually trying to do is to store a `m x n` matrix.

Usually such matrices are **not** stored in multi-dimensional structures but in linear memory. The position (row, column) of a given element is then derived based on an indexing scheme of which [row-major and column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) are used most often.

Since you already state that you will copy this data on to a GPU, this copying is then simply done by copying the linear vector as a whole.
You will then use the same indexing scheme on the GPU and on the host.

If you are using CUDA, have a look at [Thrust](http://thrust.github.io/). It provides `thrust::host_vector<T>` and `thrust::device_vector<T>` and simplifies copying even further:

```
thrust::host_vector<int> hostVec(100); // 10 x 10 matrix
thrust::device_vector<int> deviceVec = hostVec; // copies hostVec to GPU
```